# How we can download rendertable in pdf format in R shiny without losing HTML tags that I used in the table

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

### Table code in r shiny:

```
  output$TextTable <- renderTable({
    varsub
  }, width = "92%", include.colnames = TRUE, spacing = "xs",
  sanitize.text.function = identity)
```

##I want to download this renderable using a download button or link.

Comment: What do you mean by "without losing the HTML tags"? Is there some HTML code in `varsub` ?

Comment: yes, I used &nbsp and <br> for creating space and line. So my table looks fine. 
that does not want to lose in download.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the server section:

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste("test.csv")
        },
        content = function(file) {
            write.csv(varsub(), file, row.names = FALSE)
        }
    )
```

Next, add this next to your ui, like this:

```
tableOutput("TextTable"),
           downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
```

You may also refer this documentation https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/downloadHandler.html

Comment: This is CSV, I want in PDF.

Comment: Any suggestion for PDF

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using the JavaScript libraries **jspdf** and **dom-to-image**. You have to set the table id in the `data-tableid` attribute of the button.

```
library(shiny)

js <- "
function tableExport(tableId){
  var $table = $(document.getElementById(tableId));
  var captionHeight = 8 + ($table.find('caption').height() || 0);
  var container = $table.parent();
  var $el = container.hasClass('tableContainer') ? container : $table;
  var width = $el.width();
  var height = $el.height() + captionHeight;
  domtoimage.toPng($el[0], {width: width, height: height})
    .then(function (blob) {
      var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [width, height]);
      pdf.addImage(blob, 'PNG', 0, 0, width, height);
      pdf.save('table.pdf');
    });
}
"

CSS <- "
.tableContainer>* {
  margin-top: 0;
}
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js)),
    tags$style(HTML(CSS))
  ),
  br(),
  tableOutput("theTable"),
  actionButton(
    "export", "Export table to PDF", 
    "data-tableid" = "theTable", 
    onclick = "tableExport($(this).data('tableid'));"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output[["theTable"]] <- renderTable({
    data.frame(
      col1 = c("<span style='color:red;'>AAA</span>", "BBB"),
      col2 = c("CCC", "DDD")
    )
  }, width = "92%", include.colnames = TRUE, spacing = "xs",
  sanitize.text.function = identity, 
  caption = "My table", caption.placement = "bottom")
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you want to add a title to the table, proceed as follows:

```
  div(class = "tableContainer", 
      tags$h3("Table title"),
      tableOutput("theTable")
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not including Table caption and table title. Do you know how we can add these things as well?

Comment: @arinjayjain I found a way to add the caption. But how do you set a title? I don't find any title option.

Comment: Could you please share your finding to download the table with a caption. 
We can add caption on top of the table so it will be the title. Please share if you know another way to add the title.

Comment: @arinjayjain I edited my answer. Now it takes into account the caption and I give a way to add a title.

Comment: I got me wrong, I want to add this tags$h3("Table title") title in the pdf, which we are downloading.

Comment: I am getting an extra gray part in pdf above and below of table.

Comment: @arinjayjain You mean the background color of the pdf?

Comment: Yes, is it possible to set it white?

Comment: I am not getting some bottom part in like end rows and caption in my pdf.